# Invoking a static method from a subclass causes IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, visibility

When I run the source code below, the runtime error that I see in the shell window is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
pkgs.test.B.mStaPro()V from class pkgs.main.Main3
        at pkgs.main.Main3.m6(Main3.java:919)
        at pkgs.main.Main3.main(Main3.java:9)
```

What does the letter V mean, seen after the mStaPro() above?

Here is my source code, which all compiles:

class Main3, package main:

```
package pkgs.main;
import pkgs.test.B;

class Main3 {
    static public void main(String args[]) {
        new Main3().m6();
    }

    void m6() {
        B.mStaPro();
    }
}
```

class A, package main:

```
package pkgs.main;

public class A {
    static protected void mStaPro() { System.out.println("A mStaPro()"); }
}
```

class B, package test:

```
package pkgs.test;
import pkgs.main.A;

public class B extends A {
    // Note:  if this line below is commented out, then the runtime exception
    // mentioned in this post's title is not seen.
    static protected void mStaPro() { System.out.println("B mStaPro()"); }
}
```

Here are the contents of my shell-based compile and run batch files:

```
REM For compilation:
javac -Xlint -sourcepath ..\src -d ..\cls ..\src\pkgs\main\Main3.java


REM For running:
java -cp ..\cls pkgs.main.Main3
```

Please note the comment that I made inside class B.  Thanks a lot for any comments.

**EDIT:**

I tried building my source code using Apache Ant, but the result obtained is identical:

```
run:
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method pkgs.test.B.mStaPro()V from class pkgs.main.Main3
     [java]     at pkgs.main.Main3.m6(Main3.java:11)
     [java]     at pkgs.main.Main3.main(Main3.java:7)
     [java] Java Result: 1

main:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Please note that in the first exception error message at the top of this post, I had a lot of code commented out in the source code, hence the line numbers differ between that error message, and Ant's error message immediately above.

One other thing that I have tried is upgrading my JDK from version 1.7.0_40, to version 1.7.0_55.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is my Apache Ant build.xml file.  It's almost identical to the tutorial build.xml file provided on the Apache Ant website:

```
<project name="Main3 test" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="main-class"  value="pkgs.main.Main3"/>



    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" 
                includeantruntime="false" debug="true" 
        debuglevel="lines,vars,source" />
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" 
         basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

Comment: That shouldn't compile. Are you sure you didn't change the access modifier on the target method after compiling `main`?

Comment: I don't know the best way to approach this situation.  I've resaved all of my source code files, and rerun my compilation batch file, and then rerun the execute batch file, but I get the same runtime error.

Comment: I believe the "V" indicates the return type is void but not sure. Anyways, from `IllegalAccessError` docs: "Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed." Delete *all* of your compiled .class files before recompiling; simply recompiling without cleaning first is not enough, as javac isn't able to check for modified dependencies when compiling. Check out a more advanced build system such as `ant`, which handles this type of thing for you and exists to avoid these issues.

Comment: Thanks for the ant tip - I'll download it today.  I deleted my entire .class folder structure, and reran the compilation and execute batch files, but I still get the same runtime error.

Comment: You are only compiling `Main3.java` according to your file. You should  compile `A.java` and `B.java` as well.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov, if I make one very simple modification to either A.java or B.java source files, such as typing one illegal character in to them such as the letter 'x', then if I rerun the compilation batch file, I get an expected compile time error.  Doesn't this mean that when I run the compilation batch file, both A.java and B.java files are being automatically compiled, alongside Main3.java?

Comment: @Jason C, I downloaded Apache Ant and gave it a try.  I got the tutorial code working just fine.  I then switched over to my sample code above, and got the same result as before!  I have edited my original post to reflect this update.

Comment: @mystakonnfewshn Are you *sure* you don't have any other old .class files (perhaps even hidden in a .jar somewhere) from this project laying around in your class path somewhere?

Comment: Although I'm starting to wonder if perhaps you've stumbled on a compiler/JVM quirk of some kind. Static methods aren't overridable in the classic sense, and perhaps the compiler thinks that when you call B.mStaPro, you are referring to A.mStaPro (since it is visible there and valid to call it via a B), but then there is an inconsistency when at runtime, the JVM thinks you mean B.mStaPro (since it exists). I simply don't have time to test this right now but perhaps somebody else could give it a go?

Comment: @Jason C, I'm sorry, but a comment that I made about 5 minutes ago was in error.  I have not yet fixed this problem.  I posted a comment saying that I had fixed the problem by renaming all of my classes, but I made an error with the coding.  I have now deleted that comment.  I'll post an updated comment below.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jason C, Firstly I don't have CLASSPATH set. Secondly, I decided to edit my source code slightly. The edits that I made were to simply change the names of all of the classes in the source code. So, the class called Main3 became xMain3, and A became xA, etc.  Unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem.  Please note that up until using Ant today, I have never used my own .jar files!

Comment: @mystakonnfewshn Definitely wondering about quirk mentioned in my previous comment then. If somebody else could create a similar test to verify that would support that. For now as a workaround consider not using the same names for those two static methods (it doesn't make a difference anyways, you aren't actually "overriding" the one in B, just hiding A's implementation, so just pick a different name).

Comment: @mystakonnfewshn If you're starting new to a build system, use Maven or Gradle instead; Ant was good for its time, but Maven and Gradle use (somewhat-compatible) declarative build files that also handle all your dependencies.

Comment: Jason C and chrylis.  (Strange, SO won't let me notify more than one user, hence the absence of "at" signs.)  Interesting, I'll check that out.  BTW, I'm learning Java for certification, and the current topic I'm on is inheritance, hence the rather odd example I've managed to concoct! :)

Comment: Just to let anyone who may be interested know that my test project can be downloaded using the following DropBox link. Thank you. dropbox.com/s/c5jl9zvsz9hqm3v/t16.7z

Comment: I looked at your code and I put `A` in the wrong package. Therefore, I did not reproduce the problem. You really found a borderline case. See my update answer below.

Comment: @raphw, thanks so much for your investigation, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Java class is normally validated at three stages (roughly speaking):

1. At its compilation - this (obviously) happens when you compile a Java class.
2. When it is loaded into the Java Virtual Machine - this happens when you first reference a class.
3. During its actual execution - this happens the latest when you first use a specific code segment.

Most programming errors are caught by the Java compiler. However, the Java compiler is tricked by your [method shadowing (hiding)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) of the `pkgs.main.A#mStaPro` method by the `pkgs.test.B#mStaPro` method. Here is what happens:

When you compile your `Main` class, you are invoking the `static` method `mStaPro` on `B`. The question is, are you invoking the shadowed method that is defined in the `pkgs.main.A` class or the hiding method that is defined in the `pkgs.test.B` class? In this question, the Java compiler and the Java runtime come to different conclusions which is why the Java compiler approves your code while the Java runtime refuses it:

1. The Java compiler considers your code legal because it thinks that you are invoking the `mStaPro` method that is defined in `A`. The `A` class lives in the same package as `Main` such that its `protected` methods are [considered to be visible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to the `Main` class.
2. The Java runtime considers your code illegal because it thinks that you are invoking the `mStaPro` method that is defined in `B`. This method is also `protected` but it is defined in the `pkgs.test` package. Therefore, this `mStaPro` must not be invoked from `Main` which lives in a different package.

In order to inform you about this illegal code, the Java runtime throws you the `IllegalAccessError` that you encounter. Let us just go one step deeper here. If you look at the generated [Java byte code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode), the `Main#m` method is compiled as follows:

```
invokestatic  #5  // Method pkgs/test/B.mStaPro:()V
return
```

what resembles your Java source code:

```
B.mStaPro()
return           // a void return statement is implicit in Java source code
```

This compilation result is independent on whether the `B` class defines a method `mStaPro` or not. And this is the cause of the exception you encounter. In cases that the `B` class defines a method `mStaPro`, the `invokestatic` invocation is bound to the `B#mStaPro` method (what is illegal). Otherwise, the invocation is bound to `A#mStaPro` (what is legal).

To solve this problem, you should name your actual target class `A.mStaPro()` instead of invoking the method on `B`. However, I must honestly say that I find the behavior of the Java compiler counter-intuitive. A `static` method is, well, static and not dynamic. Therefore, the Java compiler should statically bind the invocation of `B.mStaPro()` to `pkgs/main/A.mStaPro:()V` at compile time. Effectively, without this assumption, the compilation could not be successful. And even better, it should simply produce a compilation error when it encounters that an inaccessible `B` is shadowing the target in `A` and that the code cannot run successfully.

Finally, a minor hint on this behavior might be given in Oracle's [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) on `static` invocation which mentions this behavior:

> The version of the hidden static method that gets invoked depends on
>   whether it is invoked from the superclass or the subclass.

And yet, this is not good enough for the reasons I mentioned above. However, I worked with Java in many years and since shadowing is not a recommended practice, I never encountered this problem. Putting it like this, you really found a borderline case.

*Info*: I posted this to the Java compiler mailing list. Once I get an answer, I will add the information to this posting.

Comment: Thanks.  This is really interesting, because after I posted my original post, I made a new test project.  I took the "streamlined/cut down" code that I pasted in to my o.p., and copied it in to a new project.  I then renamed all of its classes, to names such as Ax and Bx (from class names A and B).  I did this in an attempt to "distance" any old (A and B) class files away from this new project.  I then reran Ant's build on this new test project, which automatically includes the "clean up" functionality.  However, I still get the same problem!

Comment: BTW, I have concocted this code in an attempt to learn as much about inheritance as possible, as I want to take some Java certification exams.

Comment: As I explained in my posting, your classes do not apply inheritance since you are using `static` methods which only shadow other methods instead of overriding them. What Java version are you using? Maybe you found a compiler bug in an old version.

Comment: My tests are currently about learning what gets inherited, and what doesn't.  I like to see what happens in various situations.  I have tried upgrading my JDK from version 1.7.0_40, to version 1.7.0_55.  My environment variables JAVA_HOME (Ant) and PATH (for JDK and Ant) are up to date.  I wonder whether I should uninstall Java completely, then reinstall it..

Comment: BTW, if I declare static protected instance variables in to classes A and B, both of them named x for example, and then attempt the following access inside my "Main calling code" file: B.x ++;, then the compiler correctly flags this access attempt as an error at compile time.  The compiler only seems to get confused about static protected methods.

Comment: If you manage to pack a reproduction of your project and upload it somewhere, I will take a look at it on Monday.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but can you please point me in the direction of an online help resource that explains how to pack a reproduction of a Java project?  I'm guessing that you don't simply mean that I zip up my source code files, because there is so little code in my project, and it's all in my o.p. anyway.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like you to do, there might be something wrong with your code that you missed. I was confused about the line numbering 919.

Comment: Sure no problem!  I've just registered with dropbox, and uploaded my Windows-based project (called t16) in .7z compressed format.  It includes everything you need to compile and run the code.  I've also included a readme.txt in the project's root folder.  Thanks a lot!  https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5jl9zvsz9hqm3v/t16.7z

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
static protected void mStaPro() { System.out.println("B mStaPro()"); }
```

to

```
 static public void mStaPro() { System.out.println("B mStaPro()"); }
```

[javadocs-Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

> At the member level, you can also use the public modifier or no modifier (package-private) just as with top-level classes, and with the same meaning. For members, there are two additional access modifiers: private and protected. The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class. The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

Answer (score 0):

your class A and B are not in same package, and the function `B.mStaPro()` is `protected`, it can not be accessed from other package, you should put them in same package or make the function as public.

Answer (score 0):

You can't able to access protected methods of one package in a class(i.e. the classes other than subclasses) of other package.